# facebook open graph ios post button is disabled, content fades off

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share some stuff through my ios app, everything was working ok and was able to post using open graph api, however, now whenever I tap share and I'm taken to the fb app to compose the post, first the content is there and the navbar is blue, then the navbar turns white, and the preview of the post below the "say something about this..." textfield vanishes, and the "post" button at the top right corner of the screen is disabled.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @HugoTunius nope, I even reported it as a bug to FB, and they weren't able to reproduce it. I ended up using Parse API to share. Maybe if you report this too, they'll take a closer look.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329683/facebook-open-graph-share-from-ios-not-working-without-hitting-open-graph-debugg)

Comment: @HugoTunius seems really similar to what I was having, maybe with those IPs, the FB devs may be able to pinpoint the issue a bit better? Have you tried submitting a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/trending/

Comment: I am not convinced it's a bug yet. This feels like something that would have been found it's not like it's some kind of edge case

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any form of source control? It might be a good idea to restore your earlier code as it sounds like you've broken something in the facebook share code. Re-trace your steps and try to figure out what you changed that's causing this strange behavior.

Comment: I've done this already, I renamed the app and created a snapshot just before, but that was a while ago and I'm pretty sure the share feature worked after that. Still, it didn't work with the snapshot